# How can I use before validation callback with form object in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have a Service model/table and its registration form.

In the form I have almost all the Service's fields, but some of them I want to set a value, automatically, before validate the service object.

- Example:

-- Service Controller # create Action:

```css
def create
  @service = Service.new
  @service_form = ServiceFormObject.new(@service)

  @service_form.validate(params[:service_form_object]) and @service_form.save
  respond_with(@service_form, location: admin_services_path)
end
```

Before the @service_form object be validated I want to the @service_form duration_in_hours field be set. So I tried with that code:

-- Service Model:

```css
# Callbacks
  before_validation :set_duration

# Instance methods
private
  def set_duration
    self.duration_in_hours = (self.end_at - self.start_at) / 3600
  end
```

But the set_duration method didn't run (I put the 'byebug' gem to see if the method ran).

I think that the problem is that I create the form with form object (+ reform gem): i'm using form object to validate the service fields, intsead validate inside Service model.

```
class ServiceFormObject < BaseFormObject
```

The BaseFormObject inherit from Reform::Form:

```
class BaseFormObject < Reform::Form
```

I tried to put the before_validation and the method inside ServiceFormObject class, but I got an error: **undefined method `before_validation' for ServiceFormObject:Class**

How can I use before validation callback with form object in Rails 4?

Comment: `before_validation` is an `ActiveRecord::Callback` and your objects are only inheriting from the Reform gem.

Answer (score 11):

That means that your `ServiceFormObject` does not include validation callbacks.

Assuming that `Reform::Form` does handle `ActionModel` validations (it includes `ActionModel::Validations`), I'd try to include the `ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks` module into your `ServiceFormObject`, or even better, into your `BaseFormObject`:

```
class BaseFormObject < Reform::Form
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  #...
end
```

Can you try this out?